# How to set and read time w/o language barrier in linux?

Tags: date, locale

Currently when you run the command

```
 date
```

the output is

```
Wed Sep 18 07:23:28 EDT 2013
```

and if you want to change the date you'd have to run

```
date -s "18 SEP 2013 07:15:00"
```

if you try to change `SEP` to `9` ( month of the year )

as in run :

```
date -s "18 9 2013 07:15:00"
```

the result is:

```
date: invalid date `18 9 2013 07:15:00'
```

is it possible to simply use numbers instead of month names this way if i move to a different country i do not have to think extra in order to figure out what "SEP" means. etc.. ?

Answer (score 6):

The `GNU date` utility takes many different datetime formats. An easy one to use and remember is [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601). Here is an example:

```
date -s '2013-09-18 07:15:00'
```

You may want to consider using `NTP` and changing your timezone instead.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the [standard syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) is:

```
date 09180715
```

or

```
date 091807152013
```

Comment: We like our GNUisms :).